# Can you clone an object's parent object in php?

Tags: php

Is it possible to clone an object's parent object only in PHP? I've tried using this code but it returns a `Fatal error: __clone method called on non-object` error message.

Here's my code:

```
class A {
    public $val1=1;
    public $val2=2;
}

class B extends A {
    public $val3=3;

    public function getParent() {
        return clone parent;
    }
}

$B=new B();
$A=$B->getParent();
```

**The way I inted to use this, would be the following:** 
Let's propose I have to classes: `Table` and `Record extends Table`. The `Table` class holds information about a MySQL database table, the fields it has, the default values of these fields, the primary key, and most importantly, it holds three methods(insert, delete, update), but we will only talk about *delete* here. These three methods are stored as anonymous functions in a protected array inside the class. The delete method of the table class, tells what to do, when deleting something from the respective table.

For example, we have the following three mysql tables: *parent*, *children*, *grandchildren*. These tables are linked together in the following way: A record in the *parent* table can be linked to several records in the *children* table, while a record in the *children* table can be linked to several records in the *grandchildren* table.

So in this example, the `Table` object of the *parent* MySQL table would tell us, that WHEN we delete a record from this table, based on the primary key of the table, we should delete every record from the *children* table which is linked to this record. The delete method of the *children* table says something simmilar: when we delete a record from the table, we should delete every record from the *grandchildren* table, which was linked to the *children* table just now deleted.

When I will initialize objects in my code, I will initialize only `Record extends Table` objects. The first time, a `Table` object is initialized via a `Record extends Table` object, it should be stored in a static variable of the `Table` class, for future use, so when deleting something from a table, I don't have to make a new Record, I just use: `Table::$tables['parent']->delete(5);` which will delete the record from that table which has the primary key of 5, and will delete everything else that is needed to be deleted.

I don't know if this makes any sense(it can either be incoherensive because english is not my native tongue, or because it is rather late at my side of the Earth, and perhaps there is a much easier and cleaner solution to my problem then the one imagined by me)

Comment: That makes no sense, since `parent` is not an object, but a reference to the parent _class_. And classes cannot be cloned.

Comment: `return new parent;`

Comment: @AbraCadaver Which would hardly return a clone, would it?

Comment: It's not an object so how would you clone it?  `return clone new parent;`

Comment: @Aba which makes even less sense. The OPs issue exactly is  to assume that parent _is_ an object.

Comment: Okay, than is there any way, to separate the properties of the parent class, from the properties of the main class?

Comment: Not an elegant way, no, this is quite a strange request. Question is if you really need that, since you can treat each object as if it was an instance of the parent class. So why clone it?

Comment: @arkascha I've edited my original question, with a concrete use case I intend to use this for.

Comment: You should research `CASCATED DELETE`. Instead of having the programming language deal with children, your database will automatically do it for you (when deleting parent on cascate, it will erase every child).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't (in PHP). The proper way in this case would be:

```
class B extends A {
    public $val3=3;

    public function toA() {
        $a = new A();
        // Note: If $this->val is an object value you need to
        // use $a->val = clone $this->val;
        $a->val1 = $this->val1;
        $a->val2 = $this->val2;
        return $a;
    }
}
```

However, a proper OOP design should not require such a method. Parts which are written to handle an `A` can simply handle a `B` like an `A` since `B` extends from `A`. I mean that's one of the basic ideas of inheritance.